# Creating list of accounts with their host name and username in thunderbird

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, thunderbird

I am developing an add-on which needs to create the list of accounts with their host name and username. I am able to do that using `nsIMsgAccountManager` but when I am creating new account using manual setup the host name appears is giving me the default imap server name i.e. `imap.googlemail.com` even if i have changed it to `192.168.0.25`. Ideally I should get the host name as `192.168.0.25` but it's giving me `imap.googlemail.com`. This is the code I use:

```
    var originalAccounts = PrefValue("mail.accountmanager.accounts");
    var allServers = accountManager.allServers;
    var accounts = originalAccounts.split(",");
    var flagFirstItemIsSelected=false;

    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; ++i) {
        for (var ii=0; ii < allServers.Count(); ii++) {
            var currentServer = allServers.GetElementAt(ii).QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgIncomingServer);
            var type = currentServer.type;

          alert(accounts[i]);
            if ( accounts[i] == accountManager.FindAccountForServer(currentServer).key) {
                //          if (type == "none" || type == "pop3" || type == "imap" || type == "rss") {
              if(type != "none")
                  {
                    if((currentServer.username.toLowerCase().search("Yahoo".toLowerCase()))==-1&&(currentServer.username.toLowerCase().search("Gmail".toLowerCase()))==-1&&(currentServer.username.toLowerCase().search("Rediffmail".toLowerCase()))==-1)
                    {
                        var theListitem = accountList.appendItem("[" + type + "] - " + currentServer.prettyName, accounts[i]);
                        if(flagFirstItemIsSelected==false)
                        {
                            //accountList.selectItem( theListitem );
                            flagFirstItemIsSelected=true;
                        }
                        theListitem.setAttribute("class", "folderMenuItem listitem-iconic")
                        theListitem.setAttribute("ServerType",type);
                        theListitem.setAttribute("IsServer",true);
                        theListitem.setAttribute("IsSecure",currentServer.isSecure);
                        theListitem.setAttribute("onclick","listClicked()");
                    }
                  }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please any one tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: HI all i have found the ans why it is happening . this is happening because i have tanken incomingserver.hostname which should be incommingserver.realhostname this will give changed value of host name .

Comment: There are more issues with your code than that, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mail.accountmanager.accounts` preference directly, use `nsIMsgAccountService.accounts` instead ([nsISupportsArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISupportsArray) instance). There is actually a [code example on how one would iterate over all accounts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Thunderbird/Account_examples#Iterate_over_all_known_accounts). The property you should look at is `nsIMsgAccount.incomingServer` which is an [nsIMsgIncomingServer](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgIncomingServer.idl) instance and has all the necessary information. You probably want the properties `realHostName` and `realUsername`:

```
var accountManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger/account-manager;1"]
                               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgAccountManager);
var accounts = accountManager.accounts;
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.Count(); i++) {
  var account = accounts.QueryElementAt(i, Components.interfaces.nsIMsgAccount);
  var server = account.incomingServer;
  if (server.type == "pop3" || server.type == "imap")
    alert(server.realHostName + " " + server.realUsername)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wladimir i wil make changes accordingly .

Comment: I would like to add one thing: If you iterate over accountManager.accounts you'll receive the the accounts and identities in a different order than Thunderbird's compose editor. This might not be a problem for your addon, but it's just something to be aware of.